# How to send images in fields of a form group?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form group where I need to send two images in the profile_pic and banner_pic fields. However, all the ways that having sent the server returns me an error message stating that the values entered in the fields must be of type file.

```
handleBanner(file: File) {
    this.fileBanner = file;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
       this.eventForm.patchValue({
        banner_pic: reader.result
     });

     this.urlPreviewBanner = event.target.result;
    }
     reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
}

<div class="col s1">
            <label for="selecionarFotoBannerEvento" style="cursor:pointer;">
              <img [src]="urlPreviewBanner"
                   alt=""
                   class="responsive-img"
                   width="800"/>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col s9">
            <label for="selecionarFotoBannerEvento" style="cursor:pointer;">
              <p class="titulo-selecao-foto">&nbsp; Adicionar banner do evento</p>
              <p class="legenda">Recomendado imagens com tamanho 800x150.</p>
              <input formControlName="banner_pic" name="bannerHidden" type="hidden">
              <input 
                     (change)="handleBanner($event.target.files[0])"
                     type="file"
                     accept="image/*"
                     id="selecionarFotoBannerEvento"
                     style="display: none"/>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Currently I can display the image in preview but at the time of submitting the response the server remains stating that the values need to be of the file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have a crud example that send an image here: https://github.com/dedd1993/angular-cms/blob/master/src/app/pages/clients/client-form/client-form.component.ts.

```html
<div>
    <img class="preview-image" [src]="imageFile ? imageFile.link : 'localhost/image.png'">
    <button type="button" onclick="document.querySelector('#exampleInputFile').click()"></button>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" (change)="imagesPreview($event)" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
    imageFile: {link: string, file: any, name: string};

    constructor(){ }

    imagesPreview(event) {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (_event: any) => {
                this.imageFile = {
                    link: _event.target.result,
                    file: event.srcElement.files[0],
                    name: event.srcElement.files[0].name
                };
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    }

    save(): void {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('myImageToSend', this.imageFile.file);
        formData.append('title', 'Set your title name here');
        formData.append('description', 'Set your title description here');

        this.clientService.create(formData).subscribe(data => {});
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema é que eu tenho que enviar duas imagens em um objeto. Sua solução funciona para enviar apenas imagens, mas não é válida quando a imagem faz parte do formulário.

Comment: You can append data to a form with another fields like id, title, description, etc. This form will be send to your API as a normal a HTML form with a submit and action form... I updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think `formControlName` attribute need to be moved to other `input` tag.

```
        <label for="selecionarFotoBannerEvento" style="cursor:pointer;">
          <p class="titulo-selecao-foto">&nbsp; Adicionar banner do evento</p>
          <p class="legenda">Recomendado imagens com tamanho 800x150.</p>
          <input name="bannerHidden" type="hidden">
          <input formControlName="banner_pic"
                 (change)="handleBanner($event.target.files[0])"
                 type="file"
                 accept="image/*"
                 id="selecionarFotoBannerEvento"
                 style="display: none"/>
        </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Component

```
     <form [formGroup]="controleForm" (submit)="upload()">
      <input   #fileInput    formControlName="image" type="file">
      <input   formControlName="user" type="file">
      <button   type="submit" > Send </button>
     </form>
```

TS component

```
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {

          @ViewChild("fileInput") fileInput;

          pointControleFilter: FormGroup;
          constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

          ngOnInit() {
            this.controleForm = new FormGroup({
              nom: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])    
           });
          }

      upload()
      {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('nom', this.controleForm.get('nom').value);
        formData.append('image', this.fileInput.nativeElement.files[0]);
        this._http.post('url' , formData).subscribe((res)=>{
           /* if all is ok */
           Console.log('image has been sent')
         });
      }
    }
```